# Get offset alignment for a uniform buffer on a given device

Tags: graphics, shader, vulkan

Is there any way to receive the alignment, in bytes, of the offset within the allocation required for a buffer with usage `VK_BUFFER_USAGE_UNIFORM_BUFFER_BIT` on a given `VkDevice`?

If I already got such a `VkBuffer`, then this value can be retrieved from the `size` field of the `VkMemoryRequirements` structure received from a call to `vkGetBufferMemoryRequirements`.

But if I want to obtain this value with a given buffer, do I need to create a "dummy" buffer with size `1` (specifying size `0` yields a validation error, when the validation layer is enabled)?

Comment: Did you mean `VkMemoryRequirements::alignment` instead of `VkMemoryRequirements::size`?

Comment: Also, in the last paragraph, do you mean "obtain this value _without_ a given buffer"?

Answer (score 0):

The alignment requirement for a UBO is a device limitation: `VkPhysicalDeviceLimits::minUniformBufferOffsetAlignment`. The reason for this is that it applies not just to the requirement for the offset used when binding a buffer to a memory allocation, but also to any offsets used *within* a buffer to the start of UBO data when using that buffer as a UBO descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you're looking for an alignment for the `memoryOffset` parameter to `vkBindBufferMemory` that will be valid for any `VK_BUFFER_USAGE_UNIFORM_BUFFER_BIT` `VkBuffer` you create later. Essentially you want the worst-case / most restrictive alignment you'll get in `VkMemoryRequirements::alignment` for any such buffer. Correct?

I don't think you can directly query such a worst-case alignment. `VkPhysicalDeviceLimits::minUniformBufferOffsetAlignment` is close, but is a lower bound on the buffer-to-memory alignment requirements, not an upper bound ([[1](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VkMemoryRequirements)]):

> The `alignment` member satisfies the buffer descriptor offset alignment requirements associated with the `VkBuffer`’s usage:
>
> - If `usage` included `VK_BUFFER_USAGE_UNIFORM_BUFFER_BIT`, `alignment` must be an integer multiple of `VkPhysicalDeviceLimits::minUniformBufferOffsetAlignment`.

(This means that any `minUniformBufferOffsetAlignment`-aligned chunk within the `VkBuffer` can be used for a uniform buffer descriptor. But the base offset of the `VkBuffer` might need to be more strongly aligned than the offsets of descriptors within it).

However, if you do create a proxy `VkBuffer` and query its alignment, you are guaranteed that the alignment of other `VkBuffers` with the same usage and flags will have the same alignment requirement:

> - The `alignment` member is identical for all `VkBuffer` objects created with the same combination of values for the `usage` and `flags` members in the `VkBufferCreateInfo` structure passed to `vkCreateBuffer`.

Since the buffer size can't affect alignment, it's okay to use a tiny proxy buffer like you proposed.